# DataTable Ascending order Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have used following code for [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and result showing that is not in numeric ascending order.

For example:

I have order:
1, 
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
11

DataTable Showing result: 1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

Please help me. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").dataTable();
    $('#example2').dataTable({
      "bPaginate": true,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      "bSort": false,
      "bInfo": true,
      "bAutoWidth": false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Check for whitespace in your TD rows, 90% of the time that's what causes DataTables to mess up sorting. Or there's a tag in your TD such as span, which you can't use using datatables

Comment: Also try using this within the datatablessettings "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "sType": "html", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }

Comment: Not familiar with DataTables but it looks to me like you're sorting text rather than numerically, which would be why `10` and `11` would appear before `2`.

Comment: @freginold thanks for quick replay .sorting working text rather than numerically. so I need solution for numerically sorting

Comment: check dis http://jsfiddle.net/6Pxwy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this DataTables support thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/16261/#Comment_16261), it looks like your column is probably set to a string type instead of a numeric/integer type.

#### Here are some solutions from that page:

- Set the `sType` to `numeric`. See [this DataTables usage page](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#sType) for more details on that.
- If your numbers are part of a link, that could be why the function isn't picking them up as numbers.  Either remove the link, or try using this plugin: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#numbers_html.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention that I am using Bootstrap's DataTable, so will it work in that ?

Comment: @sandeepautade It should still work the same. If it doesn't, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with id's I wanted to sort. So my id's were strings and order: [0, 'asc'] didn't work.

The solution was using Pre-deformatting method. It's used to convert the formatted data into orderable data. So it worked with 
    order: [0, 'pre']

https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/sorting

Answer (score 1):

In case the solutions above are still not working for you, check whether you're passing a **language object** to the DataTable constructor, for example this way :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    language: { url: '/localisation/fr_FR.json' }
} );
```

In my case, that's where the problem came from. The **language object** contained this line :

```
"decimal": ","
```

For some reason, that is what was causing the issue. **By removing it, the numbers are now ordered properly.**

Of course, this only works if you don't have a need for the decimal specification in your language object.